# Is possible to load the configuration file corresponding to the domain in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, configuration-files

I have an application in Java using Spring Framework. In the application I have a class named `SpringConfiguration` that loads the server configuration. In that class I use the annotation `@PropertySource` to set the configuration file. The configuration path is a constant defined in the class `Constants` as you can see here:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( "classpath:/" + Constants.configurationFilePath )
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements AsyncConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer 
{ ... }
```

The problem is that I have several domains using this application, when I want to mount a server I need to change the value of the constant (`Constants.configurationFilePath`) in the class `Constants` like this:

```
public class Constants 
{
...


//  public static final String configurationFilePath = "com/application/live-domain1.properties";
//  public static final String configurationFilePath = "com/application/live-domain2.properties";
    public static final String configurationFilePath = "com/application/live-domain3.properties"; 
...
}
```

As you can see I simply uncomment the line of which configuration file path I want to use to generate the WAR, and obviusly comment the another constants. I need to do this always I want to generate a new WAR for another application, because each "domain" (server) has different purposes.

My idea is to use a global configuration file to point to the different configuration files.

```
@PropertySource( "classpath:/" + Constants.globalConfigurationFilePath )
```

In that configuration file I set the following properties:

```
server.domain1 = "com/application/live-domain1.properties"
server.domain2 = "com/application/live-domain2.properties"
server.domain3 = "com/application/live-domain3.properties"
```

Then when the configuration file loads, I load the configuration file corresponding to the URL of the request:

```
properties = new Properties();
finalConfiguration = new Properties();
        try
        {
            properties.load( 
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        SpringConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( 
                                Constants.globalConfigurationFilePath )
                        , "UTF-8"
                    ) 
                );      
if (url == "domain1.com") {
finalConfiguration.load( 
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        SpringConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( 
                                properties.getProperty( "server.domain1" ); )
                        , "UTF-8"
                    ) 
                );  
}
else 
...
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Error loading properties", e ); 
        }
```

The main problem is how to resolve the `url` to get the domain of the request?

Comment: Are you using three separate wars for your domains or do you want to load the property dynamically in same war based on user request?

Comment: Your application probably runs in an application server right? You could name each domain and retrieve them as system properties. As an alternative, you could also create a property file indicating the name of the  current domain.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Spring Profiles.   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: With profiles you can have profile specific properties files as well

Comment: You can also look into a config server, it's easy to set up as a soring boot app

Comment: @mirmdasif separate wars